# How to align your superscript to your main text in HTML

Tags: html

Price example:

I would like to use superscript in my price. If the price is $10 and 89 cents I would like to have the 89 cents aligned to the $10 with superscript.When using `<sup>` the superscript is applied but the "89" part goes further above then I would like.
If you take a look at the picture, the top of the 89 would have to be aligned with the top of the 10.

[image: superscript]

Answer (score 9):

```
<style>
.cents {
font-size: 70%;
position: relative;
bottom: 0.3em;
}
</style>
$100<span class=cents>89</span>
```

This works more reliably across browsers than the `<sup>` markup or the `vertical-align` property (see longish [explanation](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/#subsup)). Selecting the `bottom` value (suitable for the selected `font-size`) is not an exact science since—the idea is to move the element up the same amount as the height of the digits is reduced, but this requires some experimentation.

Comment: This was the perfect fix for another common superscript problem - trying to avoid changing the line height and messing up the position of the rest of the text / elements :-)

Answer (score 6):

Give `vertical-align: top;` to your `<sup>` tag

Comment: It usually works. But can create problems with certain font-sizes and fonts, especially when you use fonts that don't use the full height for rendering numbers. If your fonts, sizes etc. don't change much, this should be a good enough solution.

Comment: If you're not strict about HTML5, i can give you a cross-browser solution.